# Arduino Unos with ethernet shields can't communicate directly

Tags: networking, arduino, ethernet

I'm trying to connect two arduino unos with ethernet shields with each other via crossover cable.(codes taken from [server](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) [client](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient)) Both of them works when I connect them to a PC separately, however they can't communicate between each other(No lights except red on the shield lights up, connection fails). However it only works if I plug all of them in the switch. every device has static ips and the same subnet, but an interesting thing is that if I unplug the pc from the switch, arduinos stop communicating, even if the pc has a different subnet assigned.

Comment: You should give more info. At the very least, the ethernet startup code used in the two arduinos. The beheviour you are describing could have many explanations (except for the part with the communication via a switch depending on the existence of the PC in the network, which seems really strange) and you don't give us enough info to make a 'differential diagnosis'

Comment: Turns out it was cables fault, thanks for the comment :)